# How to use JUnit4 to test a void method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, methods, junit, void

So my code looks so (I know I did not write the subtraction rules but ignore that):
 The method must be declared so(its an assignment ) and I also have an interface implemented

```
public class RomanNumber implements Number {
    public String roman;

public RomanNumber(String roman) {

    this.roman = roman;
}

public void fromIntValue(int value) {
        String roman ="";
        if (value < 0) {
                roman = " ";
            }
            while (value >= 1000) {
                roman += "M";
                value -= 1000;
            }
            while (value >= 500) {
                roman += "D";
                value -= 500;
            }
            while (value >= 100) {
                roman += "C";
                value -= 100;
            }
            while (value >= 50) {
                roman += "L";
                value -= 50;
            }
            while (value >= 10) {
                roman += "X";
                value -= 10;
            }
            while (value >= 5) {
                roman += "V";
                value -= 5;
            }
            while (value >= 1) {
                roman += "I";
                value -= 1;
            }
             this.roman=roman;
    }
```

My JUnit Test:

```
public void fromIntValue() {
        RomanNumber rom = new RomanNumber("MMMCCLV");
        rom.fromIntValue(3255);
        Assert.assertEquals({"MMCCLV"},rom.fromIntValue(3255));

    }
```

And my error message:

```
Error:(26, 54) java: 'void' type not allowed here
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense for this method to be `void`. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: @kaya3 I know but my professor demanded so. Otherwise it works with String. I also have an interface implemented to the class which is also void

Comment: And what is the method supposed to do?

Comment: @kaya3 convert a arabic number to a roman and set the new value as the value of object instance

Comment: *and set the new value as the value of object instance* - so your method is not written correctly. It is supposed to change the object's state, not create a new object (which has no effect since it is not returned).

Comment: @kaya3 would you mind telling me how do I improve it?

Comment: You should be setting the field(s) of the object the method is called on, instead of a new object. I can't say anything other than that since the rest of your code isn't included in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204004/discussion-between-nsol-and-kaya3).

Answer (score 0):

Unittest verify *public observable behavior*, that is a *return value* (if any) or *communication with dependencies*.

Your code is supposed to to change the *internal state* of the object.
Accessing the internal state (the variable you store the translated number in) would violate  *Encapsulation / Information Hiding* which is one of the most important principles of *object oriented programming*.

After all a change in the objects state should result in a change of the objects  public observable behavior. In your case there should be a *getter* method exposing the internally stored roman number. So your test should use this *getter* to retrieve the state.

Comment: Interesting comment. It would be great if you support it with links documentation (or some other kind of information).

Comment: @carloswm85 The best resources on that topic I know of are some books: [Clean Code](https://www.amazon.com/-/en/dp/0132350882/qid=1605958612), [The Art of Unit Testing](https://www.amazon.com/-/en/dp/1617290890/qid=1605958703) and [Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests](https://www.amazon.com/-/en/dp/0321503627/qid=1605958825)

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the result on the private variable called `roman` but not reading it anywhere after that.

The `fromIntValue` method is being use only to trigger the conversion without return the final result (`void` return). This is why you are receiving the error.

You need to create some method to get the roman value on the `RomanNumber` class, like a `getRoman` method:

```
public String getRoman() {
     return this.roman;
}
```

So, your test could read the result:

```
RomanNumber rom = new RomanNumber("MMMCCLV");
rom.fromIntValue(3255);
Assert.assertEquals("MMCCLV", rom.getRoman());
```

Answer (score 0):

You save result into private member. For that you need to get that member using the getter method or WhiteBox class of PowerMock package.

- for getter method add into that class.

```
public String getRoman() {
     return this.roman;
}
```

- using WhiteBox add following statement into test case after method call.

String roman = WhiteBox(rom,"roman");// return the value of roman member
Assert.assertEquals("MMCCLV", roman);

```
String roman = WhiteBox(rom,"roman");// return the value of roman member
Assert.assertEquals("MMCCLV", roman);
```